# django Request aborted Forbidden (CSRF token missing.) channels websockets

Tags: python, django, channel

I'm new to django and I'm trying to get a realtime chat app using channels websockets up and running. I've tried building the chat page myself as well as copy pasting the relevant chat code from the tutorial itself. Still I get "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." and "Forbidden (CSRF token missing.):" from inside terminal. Things I've tried:

1. adding `{% csrf_token %}` above the form - then messages aren't added to the list of messages but the page reloads and the "Forbidden (CSRF token missing.):" disappears.
2. adding `@csrf_protect` in chat/views.py.
3. using channels version 3.0.5. That's the version in the tutorial.
4. I've tried rebuilding the database and deleting all migration files and restoring them. Doesn't change anything (just trying different angles)

*chat/templates/chat/chat.html*

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %} {{ chat.name }} | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}


<div class="p-10 lg:p-20 text-center">
    <h1 class="text-3xl lg:text-6xl text-white">{{ chat.name }}</h1>

</div>

<!-- div for actual messages-->
<div class="lg:w-2/4 mt-6 mx-4 lg:mx-auto p-4 bg-white rounded-xl">
    <div class="chat-messages space-y-3" id="chat-messages">
        <div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">
            <p class="font-semibold">Username</p>
            <p>This is the message for the user</p>
        </div>

        <div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">
            <p class="font-semibold">Username</p>
            <p>This is the message for the user</p>
        </div>

        <div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">
            <p class="font-semibold">Username</p>
            <p>This is the message for the user</p>
        </div>

        <div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">
            <p class="font-semibold">Username</p>
            <p>This is the message for the user</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- form for input and sending-->
<div class="lg:w-2/4 mt-6 mx-4 lg:mx-auto p-4 bg-white rounded-xl">
    <form method="post" action="." class="flex">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="content" class="flex-1 mr-3" placeholder="Your message..." id="chat-massage-input">
        <button class="px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-white bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700" id="chat-message-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{{ chat.slug | json_script:"json-chatname"}}
{{ request.user.username | json_script:"json-username" }}

<script>
    const chatName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("json-chatname").textContent);
    const userName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("json-username").textContent);
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        "ws://"
        + window.location.host
        + "/ws/"
        + chatName
        + "/"
    );

    chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("[open] Connection established");
    };

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e){
        console.log("on message");

        const data = JSON.parse(e.data); 

        if (data.message){
            let html = '<div class="p-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-xl">'
            html += '<p class="font-semibold">' + data.username + '</p>'
            html += '<p>' + data.message + '</p> </div>' 

            document.querySelector("#chat-messages").innerHTML += html;
        }else{
            alert("The message is empty");
        }
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e){
        console.log("on close");
    }

    document.querySelector("#chat-message-submit").onclick() = function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        const messageInputDom = document.querySelector("#chat-message-input");
        const message = messageInputDom.value;

        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            "message" : message,
            "username" : userName,
            "chatname" : chatName,
        }))

        messageInputDom.value = "";

        return false;
    }


</script>
{% endblock %}
```

*chat/consumers.py*

```
import json

from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.chat_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["chat_name"]
        self.chat_group_name = "%s_group" % self.chat_name 

        # add group to channel layers
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.chat_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        # connect to channel
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.chat_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data["message"]
        username = data["username"]
        chat = data["chat"]

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.chat_group_name,
            {
                "type": "chat_message",
                "message":message,
                "username":username,
                "chat":chat,
            }
        )
    
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        username = event["username"]
        chat = event["chat"]

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            "message": message,
            "username": username,
            "chat": chat,
        }))
```

*chat/models.py*

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

*chat/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
# Create your views here.
from .models import Chat

@login_required
@csrf_protect
def chats(request):
    chats = Chat.objects.all

    return render(request, "chat/chats.html", {"chats" : chats})
        

@login_required
@csrf_protect
def chat(request, slug):
    chat = Chat.objects.get(slug=slug)

    return render(request, "chat/chat.html", {"chat" : chat})
```

*djangochat/asgi.py*

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import chat.routing 
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangochat.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()



application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http" : django_asgi_app,
    "websocket" : AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

Some notes:

1. I somehow don't even see the chat sockets handshaking at all anymore.
2. `console.log` doesn't display anything and all `alert` doesn't alert anything even when message is empty and submit is clicked.
3. I've tried debugging the websocket connections but since they aren't even connecting I'm not sure how to proceed.

I'm really scratching my head here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy crap.. Figured it out. Hope this helps somebody else when using django templates and channels websockets (check all template variables carefully...)

1. There were no `console.log` messages because I was missing `{% block scripts %}` and `{% endblock %}` at the bottom of my base.html file.
2. Once fixing this the websockets connected.
3. After fixing those things then the `Request aborted Forbidden (CSRF token missing.)` message disappeared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}DjangoChat</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body class="bg-teal-600">
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between px-4 py-6 bg-teal-800">
        <div>
            <a href="/" class="text-xl text-white">Django Chat</a>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="/chats/" class="text-white hover:text-grey-200">Chats</a>

                <a href="/logout/" class="px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-white bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700">Log out</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="/login/" class="text-white hover:text-grey-200">Login</a>
                <a href="/signup/" class="px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-white bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700">Sign Up</a>
            {% endif %}
        
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block scripts %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

Also there's a typo in the chat.html, `#chat-message-input` not `#chat-massage-input` and chat.html form needs to be updated with csrf_token:

```
<div class="lg:w-2/4 mt-6 mx-4 lg:mx-auto p-4 bg-white rounded-xl">
    <form method="post" action="." class="flex">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="content" class="flex-1 mr-3" placeholder="Your message..." id="chat-message-input">
        <button class="px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-white bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700" id="chat-message-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

lastly consumers.py disconnect needs to be changed:

```
async def disconnect(self, code):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.chat_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )
```

now I can send messages successfully.